# Using select query in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

im trying to figure out how to properly use a select query in vb.net. The query im trying to use uses a join function, to join multiple tables. I also have a where filter in there. Below is the query as it works in MS SQL Server Management Studio. Can anyone here push me in to the right direction or know of a syntax/format I can use to perform this query?

```
select th.*, odo.OptionCode
from FVMASTER..trackinghistory th
join FVMASTER..OrderDetailOptions odo on odo.odKey=th.odKey
join FVMASTER..MasterPartOptions mpo on mpo.Code=odo.OptionCode and mpo. 
[Group]=odo.optiongroup 
and mpo.QuestionKey='KGLASS' and OptionType=5
where th.DateTime>DATEADD(DAY,-4,getdate()) and th.Code='__A__' and th.StationID='HO4' and 
left(odo.OptionCode,1) = 'H'
order by th.SchedID, th.UnitID, th.MasterKey
```

Comment: Usual way to work with sql in .net is using the entity framework

Comment: You already have an answer to the problem in your previous question: [SQL Select query in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030414/sql-select-query-in-vb-net).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it is done in ADO.net. You will need at the top of your file.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Something is wrong with this line of the `sqlString`. You wouldn't want a space after a period.

```
join FVMASTER..MasterPartOptions mpo on mpo.Code=odo.OptionCode and mpo.
```

You should be able to copy and paste the Select statement from SSMS directly to vb.net code.

Separate your data access code from the user interface code. It seems all your parameters are hard coded.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetThData()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetThData() As DataTable
    Dim sqlString = "select th.*, odo.OptionCode
from FVMASTER..trackinghistory th
join FVMASTER..OrderDetailOptions odo on odo.odKey=th.odKey
join FVMASTER..MasterPartOptions mpo on mpo.Code=odo.OptionCode 
and mpo. 
[Group]=odo.optiongroup 
and mpo.QuestionKey='KGLASS' and OptionType=5
where th.DateTime>DATEADD(DAY,-4,getdate()) and th.Code='__A__' 
and th.StationID='HO4' and 
left(odo.OptionCode,1) = 'H'
order by th.SchedID, th.UnitID, th.MasterKey;"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlString, cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: This might be what I'm after. The problem i now have is that DataGridView1 is not declared, do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: when i remove the where filter, it does do something. I can see that the application uses a lot of memory and the app gets really slow, probably because its requesting a ton of data. The thing is that it never shows the table with the data.

Comment: If you query runs in SSMS, it will run in vb.net. When you say a ton of data, how many rows are returned in SSMS? As far a DataGridView1 is concerned, add the control to your form. That is the default name of the first grid you add. Name it whatever you wish and change the name in the code.

Comment: Did you fix the line in the Select that I mentioned in my answer? The line that ends with a period.